# The page isn't redirecting properly only index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess

only the homepage has this issue. It says the page isn't redirecting properly my index.php has the following code

```
<?php $root = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/'; echo '<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.$root.'">'; ?>
```

and my .htaccess has this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the meta refresh to the  root of the website. so this will create redirect loop on the home/index page.

Comment: I'm a rookie some more details plz. Thanks

Comment: ok tell me why you have added this line in your code?  `<META http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='.$root.'">'; `